# Determining Component Values for a PCB Antenna

Tags: antenna, esp32

I'm trying to encorporate an [ESP32-C3FH4](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_datasheet_en.pdf) into my design, and I've reached the point where I need to design the antenna.

I think the [AN2051](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809242106_Rainsun-microwave-Tech-AN2051-245_C99727.pdf) should be a sufficient antenna component (it's an IOT device, I don't need huge data throughput, it just needs to be good enough.)

Whilst referencing Espressif's own [hardware design guide](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) I've come across this schematic in the RF section:

[image: RF Schematic - Espressif]

I've replicated this onto my design:

[image: RF Schematic - Me]

That box at the bottom gives me no guidance whatsoever as to how to determine the values for the inductor and the two capacitors. Unfortunately, antenna design was also not covered when I was at university and I can't seem to find any concise guides in this regard either.

How do I approach this? Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to use a full SoC module.

Comment: RF is it's own engineering degree entirely.  Typically, these values are determined with a [network analyzer](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/products/network-analyzers.html).

Comment: If you don't know RF design then just copy paste the provided reference design. Or otherwise you'll have to redo all the radio testing which is very expensive.

Comment: Antenna has a impedance. The PI (CLC) filter is a matching impedance filter to make the Impedance of the PCB and the PI filter equal to antenna impedance. There are look up calculators to calculate values of the PI filter. You can also do it manually. Look at RF antenna impedance matching.